# What is '1 in Collection type Name

Tags: c#, generics, collections

I was wondering what '1 means in Collection type name? For example: List'1, IList'1 Does anybody know what that is?

Comment: I always thought it was the number of generic arguments since you can overload on the number of arguments. (Which I assumed served as name mangling to differentiate the overloads)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The *backtick* indicates:

> The name of a generic type ends with a backtick (`) followed by digits
>   representing the number of generic type arguments. The purpose of this
>   name mangling is to allow compilers to support generic types with the
>   same name but with different numbers of type parameters, occurring in
>   the same scope.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1(v=vs.110).aspx